# Format strings with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have some very "messy" strings that come in like this:

- `CR 722-2018`
- `CR7222018`
- `-CR 7222018`

I need them converted into something like this:

`CP-41-CR-0000722-2018`

All three of the above would wind up looking like this.

I was curious if there was a way to accomplish this with `RegEx`? The format would look something like:

`CP-41-CR-(\n{7})-(\n{4})`.

Is this something that can be done with `RegEx`?

Comment: You dont really need Regex, you just need to strip out all non-digit characters and then interpolate the string

Comment: To expand on Maccuttura comment `"T0e1s2t3S4t5r6i7n8g9h10e11r12e13".Where(Char.IsDigit).Take(7)` A simple `.Where(Char.IsDigit).Take(7)` should do the job Is the CR important does it vary? Do you need to pad with 0 the 722 part or does it range from 001-999? Some test case to cover all edge case would be nice..

Comment: For the year par do you want to enforce the 4 digit or "`CR 72220-18`" will give a valid "`CP-41-CR-0072220-18`"?

Comment: @xdtTransform, I would want to enforce 4 digit -- default to 20xx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that can be done with `RegEx` as follows:

```cs
var patt = @".*?(CR)\s?(\d\d\d)\-?(\d\d\d\d)";

Regex.Matches(txtIn.Text, patt, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Cast<Match>()
    .ToList().ForEach(m => 
    Console.WriteLine($"CP-41-{m.Groups[1].Value}0000{m.Groups[2].Value}-{m.Groups[3].Value}"));
```

Where the `txtIn.Text` is the input of the *messy* strings.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/17) is a test.

Also the pattern `.*?(CR)\s?(\d{3})\-?(\d{4})` will [do](https://regex101.com/r/Ou5ruY/18).

Comment: May be `0000{m.Groups[2].Value}` can be written as `{m.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(7,'0')}`

Comment: @MKR uhh. Only the big boys can code like that. Thank you mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
            string[] inputs = {
                                  "CR 722-2018",
                                  "CR7222018",
                                  "-CR 7222018"
                              };
            foreach (string input in inputs)
            {
                string digits = string.Join("", input.Where(x => char.IsDigit(x)));
                string output = string.Format("CP-41-CR-000{0}-{1}", digits.Substring(0, 3), digits.Substring(3));
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```